# What is the difference between quantum correlations and entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-optics

I have been reading about Spontaneous Parametric Down Conversion(SPDC). We usually use SPDC to generate polarization entangled photons. Now I am studying about correlations of the photons in the spatial degrees of freedom. In all the papers, they never mention the word "entanglement" for spatial degrees of freedom. The papers always mention "perfect correlation" or quantum correlations. This correlations are usually quantified by pearson coefficient r. What I am confused by is how do we know if they are entangled or correlated. What is the difference in both of them.
For this I tried searching for papers on Von Neumann entropy for the SPDC photons and the entropy I calculated came out to be
$\begin{equation} 
S(r) = \frac{2}{ln2} - 2 - ln(1-r^2) - \frac{1}{(1-r^2)ln8}
\end{equation}$
where r is the pearson coefficient
But what I dont understand is that if they are not correlated(r=0), then why is there some finite entropy?

Comment: Perhaps what is meant by "correlations" is whenever a measurement results in the outcomes being the same. For example an unentangeld state can exhibit corrrelations, but these are the same correlations you would expect to find for two independent states.

Comment: @StevenSagona  Then how can I distinguish between correlation and entanglement quantitatively?

Comment: You repeat the experiment and reconstruct what the underlying wavefuintion is