# What is meant by entanglement in spatial degrees of freedom and how is it different from correlation in spatial degrees of freedom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

I am studying about SPDC (spontaneous parametric down conversion) and I come across phrases like "perfect correlation in spatial degrees of freedom" but never "entanglement in spatial degrees of freedom". Why is it so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between quantum correlations and entanglement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/786412/)

Comment: This seems like a trimmed-down version of your question from two hours ago!  Please don't repost a closed question. Your previous question was closed as a duplicate. Did you not think that the answers there answered your question?  If so, please edit your post to explain how it's different than the duplicate post and request to reopen.